# Google map not loading in angularjs and no console errors in javascript

Tags: angularjs, jquery-plugins, maps

Iam woring on google maps with angularjs 1.x and all the google maps javascript library is loaded and it is not showing on the div tag

Comment: show us the code where ur failing '

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a width and height for the the `div` that is supposed to contain the map . Please find the below map directive that I wrote, reuse and modify according to requirement.

It can be used like ,

`<map trip="latLongObj" on-create="controllerFunction()"></map>`

and the definition is ,

```
  function map($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            onCreate: '&',
            trip: '=',
            location: '@'
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element) {

            var DirectionsDisplay;
            var DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

            function initialize(trip) {
                DirectionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

                var origin = {}, destin = {};

                if (!$scope.location) {
                    origin.lat = trip.origin.latitude;
                    origin.long = trip.origin.longitude;

                    destin.lat = trip.destination.latitude;
                    destin.long = trip.destination.longitude;
                } else {
                    origin.lat = trip.location.latitude;
                    origin.long = trip.location.longitude;
                }

                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(origin.lat, origin.long),
                    zoom: 13,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    streetViewControl: false
                };


                var map = new google.maps.Map($element[0], mapOptions);

                if (!$scope.location) {
                    DirectionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                    DirectionsService.route({
                        origin: new google.maps.LatLng(origin.lat, origin.long),
                        destination: new google.maps.LatLng(destin.lat, destin.long),
                        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                    }, function (response, status) {
                        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            DirectionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                        } else {
                            $window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                        }
                    });
                }

                $scope.onCreate({ map: map });
            }

            $scope.$watch('trip', function (trip) {
                if (trip) {
                    initialize(trip);
                }
            }, true)
        }
    }
}
```

You can acheive it without having a watcher , and using ng-if while using the directive to make sure that there is data.